# How to show div when link is clicked with ng-show angular js

Tags: angularjs

first off, i have links from a json and display it using ng-repeat and i want to know if its best practise to load all object property (in a div) corresponding to its link and hide it so when you click a link, the corresponding div shows.

I'm thinking about the worst case scenario, were we have about a 100 links and the load all corresponding divs and hide it o_O

So this is my html:

```
<a href="">
  <div ng-model="showModal" class="contentItem" ng-repeat='meal in recipes | filter:searchText' ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{ meal.url }})'}">
                        <span id="contentItemHeader">{{ meal.title }}</span>
                        <span id="contentItemLevel">{{ meal.level }}</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

This is the div (modal) i want to display in full screen:

```
<div ng-show="showModal" ng-repeat='meal in recipes'>
<span>{{ meal.url }}</span>
<span>{{ meal.method }}</span>
<span>{{ meal.ingredients }}</span>
</div>
```

Use case is:

-all links loads

-click a link

-corresponding div shows

Thats it ! just like when you see a list of videos on youtube, you click one, then the video page opens but as a modal (same page)

Thanks alot,

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `$modal` service from the UI Bootstrap, define template for meal's modal and attach `ng-click` handler on each individual meal in `ng-repeat`. In click handle you can open modal and pass meal instance to modal's scope:

View:

```
<div ng-repeat='meal in recipes' ng-click='selectMeal(meal)'>
  {{meal.title}}
</div>
```

Conrtoller:

```
  $scope.selectMeal = function(meal) {
    var dialogScope = $scope.$new(true);
    dialogScope.meal = meal;

    var modalInstannce = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'meal-dialog.html',
      scope: dialogScope
    });
  };
```

Modal template:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">{{ meal.title }}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div>{{ meal.url }}</div>
  <div>{{ meal.method }}</div>
  <hr />
  <h4>Ingridients</h4>
  <ul >
    <li ng-repeat='ingridient in meal.ingridients' >{{ingridient.name}} : {{ingridient.amount}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zp6igJBvv2ijrEyWe6fv?p=preview)

To show div in question, when meal selected, introduce new `selectedMeal` property in `$scope` and use it in modal template, remove `ng-repeat` from modal div and set `selectedMeal` and `showModal` in `selectMeal` function:

```
$scope.selectMeal = function(meal) {
  $scope.selectedMeal = meal;
  $scope.showModal = true;
};

<div ng-show="showModal" >
  <span>{{ selectedMeal.url }}</span>
  <span>{{ selectedMeal.method }}</span>
  <span>{{ selectedMeal.ingredients }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot ! but what if i have my own modal template, how do i integrate it with your solution ?

Comment: @Pizzy213codes not clear what u asking about. Do you mean case if u don't use `$modal` service or same approach with different modal template?

Comment: yea without the $modal service. i already have my own modal which is in the question, how do i show that instead

Comment: @Pizzy213codes I deleted it as it mot suitt for your situation

Answer (score 0):

if your worried about performance of having all the divs exist, but hidden, consider using ng-if instead of ng-show. ng-if does not create the dom element if the expression is false.

`<div ng-if="expression">
  //element exists if 'expression' is true
</div>`

Comment: thats correct ! but would not be of use in my situation. Was just wondering if there was another way around this, so dynamically gets the object property for the link clicked cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you are ok to ahead with angular-ui then i think the accordian fits the requirement perfectly... [here's the link for angular-ui's the accordian] directive [1](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion)

angular-ui is the pure angularjs implementation of all twitter bootstrap components.

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </accordion-group>
</accordian>
```

you can have either one or all user selected link detail section open at a time...